# Pass aggregate function column with self left join

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, join, left-join

I would like to call a aggregate function (cost) once on a column and cascade it through the self left joins (used to create a permutation or combination of rows). That way I figure the cost is O(n) apposed to calling it after the joins O(row^joins). Starting with something like this:

```
id | cost 
----------
1  |  5   
2  |  10
```

I would like to do something similar to below. I can do something similar with a select into a temporary table and joining off that but **I would like to avoid using a temporary table**...

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_750309_plans AS (SELECT *, cost(id) as cost  FROM plans WHERE plans.id IN (1,2,...));

SELECT * FROM tmp_750309_plans AS t1 LEFT JOIN tmp_750309_plans AS t2 ON ...
```

I would prefer to do something like:

```
SELECT id, cost(id) as cost FROM plans AS t1
LEFT JOIN t1 AS t2 
ON t1.id != t2.id
AND ...
```

To get something like this:

```
id | cost | id | cost |
-----------------------
1  |  5   |NULL| NULL |
2  |  10  |3   | 15   |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the cost() function doing? You are not giving it any input. How would the second cost column be calculated if the cost() function does have any input parameters that come from the table(s)?

Comment: Ok I've put "id" so it can reference the row.

Comment: cost() could be 1+1 I just need to know how to cascade the column through the left joins. Is it some sort of sub-select?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "cascade". Is *cost(t1.id) + cost(t2.id)* what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create the temporary table, just make your SELECT a derived table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, cost(id) as cost  
  FROM plans 
  WHERE plans.id IN (1,2,...)
) tmp AS t1 LEFT JOIN tmp AS t2 ON ...
```

or an alternative solution with a common table expression (for PostgreSQL 8.4 and above)

```
with tmp as (
  SELECT *, cost(id) as cost  
  FROM plans 
  WHERE plans.id IN (1,2,...)
)
SELECT *
FROM tmp as T1
  LEFT JOIN tmp AS t2 ON ...
```

Comment: Postgresql doesn't seem to like that syntax but the ideas right.

Comment: @Moriarty: which syntax do you mean? For the second solution you will need at least PostgreSQL 8.4. The first solution should work with any version (at least > 8.0)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to make use of [window functions](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-window.html) see [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) example.

Example:

```
SELECT id, sum(cost) OVER (ORDER BY cost) FROM t1;
```

Comment: I was thinking about that as well, but I still haven't understood what the real question is...

Comment: I'll try make use of this today.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll work on making the question clear (as you can tell I'm struggling to explain it).